# Bring view to front even if it not in right hierarchy order

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, bringtofront, zposition

I know that "how to bring view to front", was asked many time, and I don't look for another :

```
self.bringSubview(toFront: myView)
```

My problem why this is not working is, that I have different hierarchical structure.

I have UIView on witch I add UITableView (first one), and then another UITableView (second one) on top.

Why I have two UITableView on top of each other is not important for this discussion, let just say, it need to be like that.

I have two headers, one from first and second table view. Now I would like to bring label from first table view header to front. (So that will not be blocked by second table view header)

```
    first header view
   --------------------------------------
   |                     first label    |
 -------------------------------------  |
 |                                   |  |
 |  Second label                     |---
 |                                   |
 -------------------------------------
  second header view
```

So in my little sketch, I need to bring first label on front.

I was looking at [zPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition), and it sounds right, but I couldn't make it work.

To not get some useless answers, there is a list of options that is not solution for me :

- Not to have one table behind another - I need this arrangement.
- Bring first table to front : There is a reason that this table is behind (because of cells display)
- Make second header view background opaque - Then rows, that go beneath header view will mess with header title.
- Make first label on second header view - I need to be first label on first header view (only displayed on front) because of movement of cells, animations,...

Comment: As I understand it, you would like to change the view hierarchy across view controllers without adding a subview or altering the views on top of it? I don’t think that is possible because only sibling views may overlap each other. perhaps create a ‘merging’ dequeue cell and pass data from both delegates to it, it should be just as fast if latency is an issue. Just a suggestion, good luck!

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I would like to do. But what is then zPosition if it is not that?

Comment: `zPosition`, at least as you've linked to, is for `SpriteKit` (it says so right at the top of your link). As such, working with two `UITableView`s won't work.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the link,..

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Hello you can set zposition to 1 it will bring you view to front.

```
self.myView.layer.zPosition = 1
```

Comment: This is not working. I already try this. I think the problem why this is not working is that both views, header1 and header2 doesn't have same parent view. (one have table1 and second have table2). I could be wrong, but then, please provide some more code, or example, where this is working.

Comment: you are perfect! I needed to send a custom subview behind cell. The result is `bringSubviewToFront` and `sendSubviewToBack` don't work but `zPosition = -1` works perfect